# javascript 'invalid property value' error

Tags: javascript

When I load the page at the following URL using IE9, I get an 'invalid property value' error at line 340:

http://phillipmfeldman.org/English/hangman.html#challenge

It seems as though it should be legal to assign a string--null or otherwise--to
this property.  Any ideas as to why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Well, you are trying to set `0` to `<input id="excluded2" ...>`'s `size`. You can't.

Comment: Since 0 is non negative it should not produce an error: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/text `valid non-negative integer` I get the error in Firefox as well so guess 0 isn't a valid value.

Comment: Indeed, setting the size to zero was the problem.  It is curious that IE was reporting the number of the offending line as 340 rather than 341.  This is what was throwing me off.

Answer (score 2):

according to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-size-attribute) HTML5 Spec:

The size attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a valid non-negative integer **greater than zero**.

Answer (score 0):

The original is inactive so I cant see the entire code sample, however I encountered the same error when sorting radgrid (IE9). Although my "bad" property was a result of `SortingSettings.SortedBackColor`

I solved this by adding the following setting, to the radgrid markup:

```
SortingSettings-SortedBackColor="NameYourColor"
```